# Multiple URLs for Single Custom Post Type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have an estate agency property website that has a custom post type of '*property*'. As such the current URL structure is:

```
/property/the-address-here
```

Now... on each property you can choose whether the property is for sale or to rent. I now want to keep the single custom post type but have two URLs for the single post type:

```
/property-for-sale/the-address-here
```

and

```
/property-for-rent/the-address-here
```

I've tried adding the following to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^property-for-sale/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^property-for-rent/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I just get redirected back to the original URL.

Also, I can't create a new custom post type before someone recommends that.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: That page is part of Wordpress? Because Wordpress will redirect a lot of things, and the potential answer depends on if it is Wordpress doing this, or some old settings or a script of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^property-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=property&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}, 0, 0);
```

See [add_rewrite_rule()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for more info.

Comment: Stunning! I was missing the post_type=property part of the redirect :)