# Wordpress: How-to make additional link to every post?

Tags: wordpress

For example I have such structure:

```
example.com/product/12345
```

product - custom post-type,
12345 - post slug.
I need to make additional '/go' link for each post, so 
example.com/product/12345/go, will redirect to the url which will be in meta of the 12345 post.
How I can make that? (if possible without additional plugins)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058749/multiple-urls-for-single-custom-post-type-in-wordpress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple URLs for Single Custom Post Type in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058749/multiple-urls-for-single-custom-post-type-in-wordpress)

Comment: You've got a meta box field with a url as the data you want the link example.com/product/12345/go to redirect to, is that correct?

Comment: Paul, yes right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'go_redirect');
function go_redirect() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'product\/([\d]*)\/go$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&redirect=1', 'top' );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
        $vars[] = 'redirect';
        return $vars;
    } );
}
```

In the beginning of single.php:

```
<?php 
$go = get_query_var('redirect');
$post_id = $post->ID;
if ($go) {header('Location: ' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'redirect_url', true), true, 301);}
?>
```