# Rewrite query string to allow multiple URLs for single custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I was looking at this post

[Multiple URLs for Single Custom Post Type in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058749/multiple-urls-for-single-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/50047993#50047993)

And I have a very similar situation but I can't get that result to work... I have a custom post type with a taxonomy which I am using as a query string to control content on the page.

I would like different URLs for the same post.

So...

```
luxury-yachts/my-yacht-name/?yacht-type=luxury-yachts-for-sale
luxury-yachts/my-yacht-name/?yacht-type=luxury-yachts-charter
```

Which ideally would like to rewrite to

```
luxury-yachts/luxury-yachts-for-sale/my-yacht-name/
luxury-yachts/luxury-yachts-charter/my-yacht-name/
```

I admit I am no expert in regex but everything I try doesn't seem to do a thing..

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit-

I have tried this:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^luxury-yachts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=master_yachts&yacht_types=$matches[0]&name=$matches[1]', 'top');

}, 0, 0);
```

but no joy

Comment: please edit the post, to include what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

Try regex:

```
^luxury-yachts(?:\/(?:[^\/]+))+?\/?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/krSsQX/1)

Comment: thanks but I had no joy with this.. going to try the solution below this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Given your regex input strings of:

`luxury-yachts/my-yacht-name/?yacht-type=luxury-yachts-for-sale` and `luxury-yachts/my-yacht-name/?yacht-type=luxury-yachts-charter`

Pattern: `~^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\?yacht-type=(.+?)/?$~`
Replace: `$1/$3/$2/`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1VyYP3/2)

Based on this reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I think you want this:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\?yacht-type=(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&yacht_types=$matches[3]&name=$matches[2]', 'top');
}, 0, 0);
```

Or:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\?yacht-type=(.+?)/?$', '$matches[1]/$matches[3]/$matches[2]/', 'top');
}, 0, 0);
```